# Is there a way to embed a 360-degree image using Vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, jpeg, vuetify.js

Is there a way display a 360-degree image using Vuetify?  I recently purchased a camera to take a 360-degree photos.  The image file is a JPG that looks distorted.  The only ways I have found to display require using an  tag.  Would like to have on a Vue site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Vue port of panorama.js - https://github.com/mudin/vue-panorama